# How can I chage the index count in a matrix? (Python)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks something like this:

```
matrix = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

If I wanted to find the value in the first spot inside the matrix I would have to do something like this:

```
matrix[0][0]
```

Is there any way in which I can make it so instead of having to input coordinates to find the position I can just ask for the specific position?

So say if I wanted the first position I would input

```
matrix[1]
```

Instead of

```
matrix[0][0]
```

If I wanted the second position I would just input

```
matrix[2]
```

instead of

```
matrix[1][0]
```

and so on.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? This is an odd way of accessing the information in a matrix. A possible solution is to flatten the matrix, but that depends on if you need it to be in matrix form for other parts of your code.

Comment: It's for a game. Inputting just the position would be a lot easier than having to find the x and y coordinate every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simplest (and cleanest) solution to do that is to wrap your matrix inside a class, and define the bracket operator for the class. However, be aware that usually, positions go from 0 to n-1, not from 1 to n.

The code is compatible with both python 2 and python 3

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix
        self.n = len(matrix)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        index -= 1
        return self.matrix[int(index%self.n)][int(index/self.n)]

a = [[1,5,9,13],
     [2,6,10,14],
     [3,7,11,15],
     [4,8,12,16]]

mtx = Matrix(a)
print([ mtx[i] for i in range(1,17) ])
# [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```